# Short Definition of Backpropagation and Gradient Descent

Tags: machine-learning, gradient, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I need to write a very short definition of backpropagation and gradient descent and I'm a bit confused what the difference is.

Is the following definition correct?:

> For calculating the weights of a neuronal network the backpropagation algorithmn is used. It's a optimization process of reducing the model error. The technique is based on a gradient descent method. Conversely, the contribution of each weight to the total error is calculated from the output layer across all hidden layers to the input layer. For this, the partial derivative of the error function  E  to  w  is calculated. The resulting gradient is used to adjust the weights in direction of the steepest descen:

```
w_new = w_old - learning_rate* (part E / part w_old)
```

Any suggestions or corrections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First gradient descent is just one of the method to perform back propagation other than this your definition is correct. We just compare the result generated with desired value and try to change the weights assigned to each edge so as to make the errors as low as possible. If after changing the error increases it reverts back to previous state. The learning rate which you are choosing should not be very low or very high otherwise it would lead to vanishing gradient or exploding gradient problem respectively and you wont be able to reach the minimum error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So then this might be better: "One way to perform backpropagation is by a gradient descent method" ?

Comment: the problem with gradient descent is it may sometimes find local minima not the global one so in that case stochastic gradient descent works better .hope it helps

Comment: ah you refer to the different variations like sgd, batch gradient descent and mini batching right?

Comment: yeah depending on needs the choice varies

Comment: Okai so then after my definition I could write something like: Dependend on the amount of training data used for one backpropagation, we can perform sgd, batch gd, or mini batching ?:)

Comment: no process is perfect in machine learning ,the choice depends on the type of data,the value of parameters u r using and a lot of hit and trials